# How to get the darker color upon having a light one?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uicolor, cgcolor

i have a color code coming from server and I am using that color to set the color of a UIView. Now I want to set the border of the UIView with a color which is darker(higher in intensity) than the color that I am getting. How can this be possible ? Please let me know and do tell me if you have any ideas to do the same.

```
view.backgroundColor = [view setColor].CGColor;
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
const CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents(view.setColor.CGColor);
NSLog(@"Red: %f", components[0]);
NSLog(@"Green: %f", components[1]);
NSLog(@"Blue: %f", components[2]);
NSLog(@"Alpha: %f", CGColorGetAlpha(view.setColor.CGColor));

/*need to set this border color as a dark color*/<br>
view.layer.borderColor = [view setColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take each color value down a notch. So something like

`[UIColor colorWithRed:oldRed*0.75f green:oldGreen*0.75f blue:oldBlue*0.75f alpha:1.0]`

Comment: It worked...thanks vakio. Well,to make it even darker do I need to multiply with a smaller value ? For example with 0.45 ?

Comment: one more thing vakio...if at all I make the alpha of the rect as 0.5...then does this also effect it's border and the transparency of the border also increase ?

Comment: Yes, the opacity of the layer extends to the border. If you want a view with just a border and no interior set the backgroundColor to clearColor and opacity to 1.0.

Comment: thanks vakio, but what I actually want is that; there is a color coming from the server; now I want to have a lighter shade of that color as the color of the view and a darker shade of that color to be put to the border; this is actually the requirement...can you suggest, what would be the best approach ??

Comment: I think you got it right now. But if you want transparency just set it in the alpha of the color and not the view so you can separate the border opacity from the background opacity.